# A-frame: How to save inspector changes made with the 3d widget to the clipboard

Tags: aframe

I am using the a-frame inspector to make changes to the position, rotation, scale of objects. I am then using the `copy entity HTML to clipboard` function.

I notice that if I make changes by typing in new values in the right hand column, the changes are saved out. If I make changes using the 3D widget however, they are not.

Example workflow:

Add a box

`<a-box></a-box>`

View page, box position at `0 0 0`.

[image]

Move box with 3D widget, values are updated in right hand column.

[image]
[image]

Press `copy entity HTML to clipboard` and paste back into the editor, this is the result.

`<a-box material="" geometry=""></a-box>`

As you can see the position changes are not saved.

If I change the values in the right hand column however, they are saved. I notice that when I do it that way as well, the `position` label (or whatever the effected element is) becomes bold as to indicate that changes have been made.

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, why is that? It would be good to be able to simply move, rotate and scale manually using the widget and have those changes saved.

Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong? Any advice much appreciated as ever.

Answer (score 2):

Probably is due to performance issues with the DOM and CPU. A-Frame will only update in debug mode the component’s serialized representation in the actual DOM.

You can manually update components using flushToDOM() but I'm also facing this error, component position values are not updating using the 3D editor, they only update when I select the values on the panel.

It seems that some function is running when selection position/rotation/scale components on the panel that is updating the values.

I have already opened an issue.

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4084

Let's see if they can help us.

BR

Answer (score 0):

Using the `flushToDom()` you can force the attributes to be persisted to the html element.

```
let box = document.query('a-box');
box.flushToDom();
```

now when you `copy entity HTML to clipboard`, the HTML should contain all your attributes as you expected.

Read more about this function in the docs: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/core/component.html#flushtodom